# How to create a boxplot of multiple rows?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe of 1200 probes (in rows) and two sets of arrays of nine column each. The first nine columns are named as "positive" and the next nine as "negative". I want to show that the expression is normal by choosing 12 random probes using box plot. My code looks as follows:

```
f<-c(rep("positive", 9), rep("negative", 9))
for(i in seq(from=1, to=1200, by=10)){
    boxplot(probes[i]~f,col="lightblue",main="Expression of genes studied Cells")
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = probes[i] ~ f) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'f')
```

If I use the box plot for a single probe it works fine. I get two boxes, one corresponding to "positive" and another to "negative":

```
f<-c(rep("positive", 9), rep("negative", 9))
genex<-as.numeric(dat.fp.labeled["NM_139321.1_psr1_at",])
boxplot(genex~f,col="lightblue",main="Expression of NM_139321.1_psr1_at samples")
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the structure of your data? Is `probes` a vector? If not, then you're indexing it incorrectly in your call to `boxplot`. Also, your current code will create 120 boxplots, but I don't think that's what you want to do...

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple boxplots grouped by two conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124827/multiple-boxplots-grouped-by-two-conditions)

Comment: It is a dataframe, containing 1200 rows and 18 columns.The eighteen columns are of two types. First 9 are named as "positive" and the next 9 are named as "negative". If I do for a single row it works fine generating two boxes each one for posive and negative. The code: is: f<-c(rep("positive", 9), rep("negative", 9))
genex<-as.numeric(dat.fp.labeled["NM_139321.1_psr1_at",])
boxplot(genex~f,col="lightblue",main="Expression of NM_139321.1_psr1_at samples")

Comment: So, your intended result is one plot containing columns labeled positive as one box and all columns labeled negative as a second box in the same plot? And do you want these as separate plots for the twelve random rows or the twelve random rows combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, I think, is what you want:

```
set.seed(1)
probes <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1200*18),ncol=18))
f<-c(rep("positive", 9), rep("negative", 9))
myrows <- sample(1:1200,12,FALSE)
boxplot(unlist(probes[myrows[1],])~f) # first plot
for(i in myrows){
    boxplot(unlist(probes[i,])~f)
    Sys.sleep(1) # wait for each plot for 1 sec
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the sample code. I have a question: Where will I put my data? In your code you are creating the data frame, probes. Let us say my data is in a data frame named data.fp, where could I put in your code? Thanks

Comment: Inside the for-loop, where it says `unlist(probes[i,])`. If you change that to `unlist(data.fp[i,])`, I think you should get the intended result.